# Dynamic Content Java Android ViewFllipper

Tags: java, android, dynamic, viewflipper

This is my Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 
 <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/viewFlipper1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
         android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
         android:background="@android:color/white" >
       **<include android:id="@id/*1*" layout="@layout/*layout1*"/>"
       <include android:id="@id/2" layout="@layout/layout2"/>   
        <include android:id="@id/3" layout="@layout/layout3"/>**

    </ViewFlipper>
</Relativelayout>
```

And this is inside onCreate

```
LinearLayout **layout1** = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.**layout1**);
TextView tv = new TextView(this); 
tv.setText("Dynamic Text!");
**layout1**.addView(tv);
```

All working fine , I just cannot load any Dynamic content inside of my layout.xml

I've try to use 1 and layout1 but the error that I m getting is that cannot finde my layout

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: there is no requirement to give id in include, and also give layout height & width in include. you can fetch your linearlayout by providing "layout1" id